# can't access this in init block

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm newbie in kotlin.How can it be that within `init` block `this` is exist and have correct type but when I try to access it, it throws null pointer exception?

```
class GameGLSurface(context: Context,attrs:AttributeSet): GLSurfaceView(context,attrs) {
    val renderer:GLRenderer= GLRenderer(context,this)
    init {
        println("surface exists:${this!=null},${this is GLSurfaceView}")// says true,true
        this.renderMode= RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY //throws NPE
        setRenderer(renderer)
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GameGLSurface 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"                            
             android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                                                         
             android:id="@+id/gl_surface"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set renderer first:

```
class GameGLSurface(context: Context,attrs:AttributeSet): GLSurfaceView(context,attrs) {
    val renderer:GLRenderer= GLRenderer(context,this)
    init {
        println("surface exists:${this!=null},${this is GLSurfaceView}")// says true,true
        setRenderer(renderer)
        this.renderMode= RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY //throws NPE
    }
}
```

should work

Comment: yeah just realized it too :)

Answer (score 0):

NPE is not due to `GlSurface` isn't created, but due to thread that updates surface is not created since renderer is not set yet.
The solution is to set renderer first and then change renderMode

```
init {
        setRenderer(renderer)
        renderMode= RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY
    }
```

silly mistake